# What will I miss if I start watching Naruto from episode 26 (recap episode)?

Tags: naruto

I want to go through the story as fast as possible so I can watch *Shippuden*. I watched some of it when I was a kid but I forgot almost everything. However, episode 26 shows the recap, so will I miss anything important if I start there?

Comment: Even if it is a recap, [you will miss the development of the story](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6037/20275)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, although you will miss the character building stuff and some content that may be referenced in the future, so make sure you atleast read the synopsis or summary of the episodes.